# Why NaN values are found in score from kfoldPredict?

Tags: matlab, classification, random-forest, ensemble-learning, k-fold

```
Names = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'};
isCategoricalPredictor = [false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false];
        
% Use tree learner
template = templateTree('NumVariablesToSample', 'all',... % to analyse predictor importance
    'Reproducible',true, 'Surrogate','on', 'MaxNumSplits', maxNumSplits, 'MinLeafSize', minLeafSize); % Surrogate on to obtain measure of association
   
% optimizable variable does not accept
BestEnsembleMdl = fitcensemble(X_train,y_train,...
    'Learners',template, ...
    'Method', method, ...
    'NumLearningCycles', numLearningCycles, ...
    'Holdout', 0.2, ...
    'LearnRate', learnRate, ...
    'ScoreTransform','logit',... % transform scores to probabilistic estimates
    'CategoricalPredictors', isCategoricalPredictor,...
    'PredictorNames', Names);
[~, score] = kfoldPredict(BestEnsembleMdl);
```

Attached mat file: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/417568/simple.mat

Hi, I tried to run `kfoldPredict` using Classification Partitioned Ensemble produced by `fitcensemble` method.

When I run `kfoldPredict`, there are many NaN values found in the `score` variable returned by `kfoldPredict` method. Refer to the `score` variable in the attached mat file.

I am expecting to get real values from the `score`.

From example above, I use the following values:

- learnRate = 0.9702
- maxNumSplits = 16826
- method = 'LogitBoost'
- numLearningCycles = 2
- minLeafSize = 1

I have saved X_train & y_train variables in the attached mat file. I have reduced the number of rows in `X_train` & `y_train` to 10 rows as a demonstration.

1. Why there are NaN values in the `score`?
2. What should I do to ensure that there are no NaN values in the `score`?

Thank you